# Excel: Limiting the value

Tags: excel

Can someone help me regarding my issue with Excel? Actually, I have two scenarios:

1st issue: My summary is in Sheet 1, whule the raw data is in sheet 2. What I want to happen is to copy the value in Sheet 2 to Sheet 1. To do that, I know that I need to perform vlookup. However, what I want to happen is this:

When the value in Sheet 2 is beyond 8 hours, I want the value in Sheet 1 to be at exactly 8 hours only. For example, sheet 2 shows the total logged in hours of 8:04 (8 hours and 4 minutes), I want the data in sheet 1 to be at exactly 8 hours only.

Note: This should be in hours format

Second issue: This is the vice versa of issue number 1, if the value in sheet 2 is less than 30 minutes, I want the data in sheet 1 to be at exactly 30 minutes.

Note: This should be in minutes format

Hope you can help.

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: Here's the code I use: =VLOOKUP($A$1,Davied!$F$1:$O$23,2,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using IF formulas. Replace A1 with your Vlookup formula:

```
=IF(A1<0.000347222222222222,0.000347222222222222,IF(A1>0.00555555555555556,0.00555555555555556,A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In excel one day equal 1 (integer), a day and a half is 1.5 (decimal) and so on.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A$1,Davied!$F$1:$O$23,2,FALSE)>1/3,1/3,
IF(VLOOKUP($A$1,Davied!$F$1:$O$23,2,FALSE)<1/48,1/48,
VLOOKUP($A$1,Davied!$F$1:$O$23,2,FALSE)))
```